# undefined method `deliver_sent' for MailerFormError:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm upgrading rais 2.3.2 project to rails 3

Error:

```
undefined method `deliver_sent' for MailerFormError:Class
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/leads_controller.rb:72:in `block in create'
app/controllers/leads_controller.rb:56:in `create'
```

MailerFormError is my model:
 `class MailerFormError < ActionMailer::Base`

It's no method 'deliver_sent' in model and Actionmailer::Base too :(

code with it in controller:

```
    @msg = {}
    @msg["errors"] = @lead.errors
    @msg["params"] = params
    MailerFormError.deliver_sent(@msg)
```

Actionmailer version:   actionmailer (3.2.11)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) for Rails 3, to send your notification in your controller , I write this :

```
    MailerFormError.sent(@msg).deliver
```

2) And I rewrite your 'sent' method in the Rails 3 way :

```
    def sent(msg, sent_at = Time.now)
      ...
      mail(:to => '...', :from => '...', :subject => '...') do |format|
        format.html
        format.text
      end
      ...
    end
```

Finally I create the text version and html in your view directory app/views/mail_form_error : sent.text.erb and sent.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Sending e-mails changed a lot between 2.3 and 3.2. Here is a basic howto:
http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/action_mailer.html