# rails actionmailer error with 'part' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm upgrading rails 2.3.2 app ot rails 3.
Have unknown error with sending email message in MailerFormError.
MailerFormError is my model: class MailerFormError < ActionMailer::Base

At 1st I have error with 'deliver_send' method ([undefined method `deliver_sent' for MailerFormError:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603423/undefined-method-deliver-sent-for-mailerformerrorclass)), 
I change it to 'send'. Now I have this:

```
   NoMethodError in LeadsController#create
   undefined method `part' for #
```

My code in controller:

```
    @msg = {}
    @msg["errors"] = @lead.errors
    @msg["params"] = params
    #MailerFormError.deliver_sent(@msg)
    MailerFormError.sent(@msg)
```

This is my class with sending method:

```
      def sent(msg, sent_at = Time.now)
        @subject    = ("Ошибка при заполнении формы").force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
        @recipients = 'mymail@gmail.com'
        @from       = 'mymail@gmail.com'
        @sent_on    = sent_at
        @headers    = {}

        part( :content_type => "multipart/alternative" ) do |p|
          p.part :content_type => "text/plain", 
                 :body => render_message("sent.plain.erb", :msg=>msg )
        end

      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) for Rails 3, to send your notification in your controller , you have to write this :

```
MailerFormError.sent(@msg).deliver
```

2) And you have to rewrite your 'sent' method in the [Rails 3 way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) :

```
def sent(msg, sent_at = Time.now)
  ...
  mail(:to => '...', :from => '...', :subject => '...') do |format|
    format.html
    format.text
  end
  ...
end
```

You can also create the text version and html in your view directory app/views/mail_form_error : sent.text.erb and sent.html.erb

Comment: My view directory must be app/views/mail_form_error. Thanks a lot! It works now